# MySQL: Select comments and the number of replies a topic have

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table named Topics where I store my forum topic:

```
topic_id
topic
description
created_by
date_created
status
```

Another table Posts where I store the comments of a topic:

```
post_id
topic_id
user_id
content
date_created
```

Then third column which is Comments table where I store the replies of a comment:

```
comment_id
topic_id
post_id
user_id
reply_to_id
comment
date_created
```

How can I count the total number of comments and replies of each topic using a MySQL statement?

EDIT: So far I tried this, but I'm not getting the right numbers

```
SELECT topics.topic_id,topics.topic, (COUNT(comments.topic_id)) AS count_comments 
FROM topics 
left join comments on topics.topic_id = comments.topic_id 
left join posts on topics.topic_id = posts.topic_id
WHERE topics.created_by != 'Admin' and topics.status = '1' 
GROUP by topics.topic_id
```

Comment: MySQL query @fvu

Comment: My bad, yes @fvu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Subqueries to achieve it:

```
SELECT `topics`.`topic_id`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE (`comments`.`topic_id`=`topics`.`topic_id`)) `comments_count`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.`topic_id`=`topics`.`topic_id`)) `posts_count`
FROM `topics`
WHERE (`topics`.`created_by` != 'Admin') AND (`topics`.`status` = '1')
```

Comment: Hi! So basically, I already got it working. When I came back here to post my answer, I found yours. And yours is the same I got so I accepted your answer. Wished I could have checked your answer earlie, wasted a few minutes but thanks for your effort cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   tpc.topic , 
         Count(cmt.comment) AS number of comments, 
         count(pst.content) AS number OF replies 
FROM     post pst, 
         comments cmt, 
         topics tpc 
GROUP BY tpc.topic_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still no go, I'm not getting the right count